# matching items from two list in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, loops

my current problem is I have two mongodb collections. My code in essence takes each name from table 1 which is 250000~ items then it compares against the list of names from table 2 (3000~) to try and match.

now I'm just brute forcing this by going through every item in the 250000 list and looking at every item in the 3000 list to see if it matches

the problem is that this takes about 2 hours to run through

Is there a faster way to do matching? I've put the stripped down version of my code below so you can see it's a simple loop in a loop.

Thanks

```
const SCCM = await ProgramDev.find({})
const Cat = await Software.find({})

for (var i = 0, len = SCCM.length; i < len; i++) {
       
        for (var n = 0, Catlen = Cat.length; n < Catlen; n++) {
    
            var program = SCCM[i]['program name']
            var software = Cat[n]['Application']
            var sat = Cat[n].Status

            if (SCCM[i].Status == undefined) {

                if (program == software) {

                    SCCM[i].Status = sat

                    break

                } 
            }
        }

        if (SCCM[i].Status == undefined) {
            SCCM[i].Status = "Un-authorised"
            SCCM[i].matchType = "None"
        }

       
    }
```

Comment: Does the values you are comparing are unique?
SCCM[i]['program name']  and  Cat[n]['Application']

Comment: @RutvikJoshi SCCM has duplicate entries Cat is unique

Answer (score 0):

If you have already extracted each name from collection1 and from collection2 into arrays this should work faster

```
array1 = ['john','smith','vova','putin', 'eug', 'hilly', 'tom', 'smith','vova','putin' ]
array2 = ['vova', 'dr.cacis']

const newArray = array1.filter(value => array2.includes(value));

console.log(newArray);
```

Output matches

```
[ 'vova', 'vova' ]
```

You can also use [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)
or [Array.prototupe.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: sorry how would I use this in the context of what I'm doing I dont want to merge the data together I want to see if the names match and if they do add the cat status field to the SCCM status field.

Comment: @adamWadsworth Can you show us 30-40 rows from your collections?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use map if you don't have memory restriction and put the values of Cat in the map like:

```
var catMap = new Map();
for (var n = 0, Catlen = Cat.length; n < Catlen; n++) {
     catMap.set(Cat[n]['Application'] , Cat[n].Status);
}
```

And run the second loop on SCCM like:

```
for (var i = 0, len = SCCM.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (SCCM[i].Status == undefined && catMap.has(SCCM[i]['program name'])){
        SCCM[i].Status = catMap.get(SCCM[i]['program name']);
    }else if(SCCM[i].Status == undefined){
        SCCM[i].Status = "Un-authorised"
        SCCM[i].matchType = "None"
    }
}
```

So, the first loop will take O(n) and second loop will take O(m), total will be O(m+n) time complexity.

The space complexity will be O(n) because of map.
Overall, program will take less time to run.

Comment: Sorry I want to try this out but do you mean to put the SCCM loop inside the CatMap loop so lit looks like this. http://codebin.herokuapp.com?s=5fd72701c060f30004000004

Comment: Both loops are separate, not nested I will change the code in the link you share.
http://codebin.herokuapp.com?s=5fd749c6c060f30004000006